# makefile no such file or directory found

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am having trouble with the following code.

```
CFG_PATH := cfg_path

include ${CFG_PATH}/makefile.cfg

INPUT_DIR=${PROG_INPUT_DIR}/input

MANIFEST_FILE = ${MANIFEST_DIR}/manifest.xml

$(shell mkdir -p ${INPUT_DIR})

Some_Target:
.
.
.
.

Target:
```

When I call this makefile from another makefile it is failing at the include line and I get the following error

```
ERROR: ${CFG_PATH}/makefile.cfg no such file or directory found.
```

In our current system, this code work fine as is and it executes fine but when I try to call it from another makefile it fails and I get that error

How I am calling the makefile.

```
${MAKE} Target -f ${makefile_location}/makefile
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do print debugging by adding `$(shell pwd)` before the offending line. Should give you a hint of what is going on.

Comment: It gave me a missing a operator error at that line you suggested

Comment: That error message is not something that GNU make would generate.  DId you copy and paste it directly from the output you got?  What version of make are you running?  What does the parent make print as the command line when it invokes the sub-make?

Comment: The exact error from the console is cfg/makefile.cfg: No such file or directory

I do wonder tho since the parent makefile also opens the same cfg file if that is causing the issue.

Comment: How do you invoke the makefile in that _current system_ where _this code work fine_?